# QTSurfaceView, SurfaceView and Z-order

Tags: android, qt, opengl-es, qml, surfaceview

I'm currently working on an Android app (4.4) for an embedded device. We are using both QT / Qml (5.6.0) for the User interface, and a native Video player which depends of a SurfaceView.

Previously, we were using 2 differents activities, but we had lot of sync issues to show the video at the good time. So we decided to merged both activities by implementing the surfaceView for the video in the tree of the QT App. The tree is :

FrameLayout
|
|-------RelativeLayout
|-------|
|-------|-------SurfaceView (VOD Player)
|
|
|-------QtLayout
|-------|
|-------|-------QtSurfaceView

Everything is working fine at the first start, the VOD is shown behind the interface. adb shell dumpsys gives the following informations :

```
adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger
Visible layers (count = 6)
+ Layer 0x14cf518 (com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper)
      z=    21000, pos=(0,-256), size=(1280,1280), isOpaque=1, needsDithering=0, invalidate=0, alpha=0xff, flags=0x00000001, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0x14d00a0, identity=3
      format= 2, activeBuffer=[1280x1280:1280,  5], transform-hint=0x00, queued-frames=0
            mBufferCount=2, mSynchronousMode=1, default-size=[1280x1280], mPixelFormat=5, mTexName=-1563003837
            current: {crop=[0,0,0,0], transform=0x00, current=-1}
            next   : {crop=[0,0,-1,-1], transform=0x00, FIFO(0)={}}
             [00] state=FREE    , crop=[0,0,0,0], transform=0x00, timestamp=355968597417
             [01] state=FREE    , crop=[0,0,-1,-1], transform=0x00, timestamp=0
  Region transparentRegion (this=0x14cf6b8, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region transparentRegionScreen (this=0x14cf54c, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region visibleRegionScreen (this=0x14cf528, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
+ LayerDim 0x14ca948 (DimSurface)
      z=    21009, pos=(0,0), size=(1280, 768), isOpaque=0, needsDithering=0, invalidate=0, alpha=0xff, flags=0x00000001, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0x14d0040, identity=6
  Region transparentRegion (this=0x14caae8, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region transparentRegionScreen (this=0x14ca97c, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region visibleRegionScreen (this=0x14ca958, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
+ Layer 0x14d4b10 (SurfaceView)
      z=    21010, pos=(0,0), size=(1280, 767), isOpaque=1, needsDithering=0, invalidate=0, alpha=0xff, flags=0x00000000, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0x14cfdb8, identity=27
      format= 1, activeBuffer=[ 720x 480:4096,100], transform-hint=0x00, queued-frames=0
            mBufferCount=8, mSynchronousMode=1, default-size=[1280x767], mPixelFormat=256, mTexName=1995859160
            current: {crop=[0,0,720,240], transform=0x00, current=7}
            next   : {crop=[0,0,720,240], transform=0x00, FIFO(0)={}}
             [00] state=DEQUEUED, crop=[0,0,720,240], transform=0x00, timestamp=568781738286, 0x14d35d0 [ 720x 480:4096,100]
             [01] state=DEQUEUED, crop=[0,0,720,240], transform=0x00, timestamp=568646942144, 0x14d3900 [ 720x 480:4096,100]
             [02] state=DEQUEUED, crop=[0,0,720,240], transform=0x00, timestamp=568814239507, 0x14d9270 [ 720x 480:4096,100]
             [03] state=DEQUEUED, crop=[0,0,720,240], transform=0x00, timestamp=568616149907, 0x14d9300 [ 720x 480:4096,100]
             [04] state=DEQUEUED, crop=[0,0,720,240], transform=0x00, timestamp=568748077398, 0x14d3390 [ 720x 480:4096,100]
             [05] state=DEQUEUED, crop=[0,0,720,240], transform=0x00, timestamp=568681243902, 0x14cbe48 [ 720x 480:4096,100]
             [06] state=DEQUEUED, crop=[0,0,720,240], transform=0x00, timestamp=568714294439, 0x14d7740 [ 720x 480:4096,100]
            >[07] state=QUEUED  , crop=[0,0,720,240], transform=0x00, timestamp=568846710210, 0x14d7920 [ 720x 480:4096,100]
  Region transparentRegion (this=0x14d4cb0, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region transparentRegionScreen (this=0x14d4b44, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region visibleRegionScreen (this=0x14d4b20, count=1)
    [  0,   0, 1280, 767]
+ Layer 0x14d6b68 (SurfaceView)
      z=    21015, pos=(0,0), size=(1280, 767), isOpaque=0, needsDithering=0, invalidate=0, alpha=0xff, flags=0x00000000, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0x14cfdb8, identity=23
      format= 1, activeBuffer=[1280x 767:1280,  5], transform-hint=0x00, queued-frames=1
            mBufferCount=2, mSynchronousMode=1, default-size=[1280x767], mPixelFormat=5, mTexName=1984777172
            current: {crop=[0,0,0,0], transform=0x00, current=1}
            next   : {crop=[0,0,0,0], transform=0x00, FIFO(1)={00 }}
             [00] state=QUEUED  , crop=[0,0,0,0], transform=0x00, timestamp=568865600591, 0x14d93a8 [1280x 767:1280,  5]
            >[01] state=QUEUED  , crop=[0,0,0,0], transform=0x00, timestamp=568846252446, 0x14d9238 [1280x 767:1280,  5]
  Region transparentRegion (this=0x14d6d08, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region transparentRegionScreen (this=0x14d6b9c, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region visibleRegionScreen (this=0x14d6b78, count=1)
    [  0,   0, 1280, 767]
+ Layer 0x14ca420 (com.******.ux.qml/com.******.ux.qml.*****Activity)
      z=    21020, pos=(0,0), size=(1280, 767), isOpaque=0, needsDithering=0, invalidate=0, alpha=0xff, flags=0x00000000, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0x14cfdb8, identity=22
      format= 1, activeBuffer=[1280x 767:1280,  5], transform-hint=0x00, queued-frames=0
            mBufferCount=2, mSynchronousMode=1, default-size=[1280x767], mPixelFormat=5, mTexName=229433297
            current: {crop=[0,0,0,0], transform=0x00, current=1}
            next   : {crop=[0,0,0,0], transform=0x00, FIFO(0)={}}
             [00] state=DEQUEUED, crop=[0,0,0,0], transform=0x00, timestamp=565950469976, 0x14d8520 [1280x 767:1280,  5]
            >[01] state=QUEUED  , crop=[0,0,0,0], transform=0x00, timestamp=565995605474, 0x14d3628 [1280x 767:1280,  5]
  Region transparentRegion (this=0x14ca5c0, count=1)
    [  0,   0, 1280, 767]
  Region transparentRegionScreen (this=0x14ca454, count=1)
    [  0,   0, 1280, 767]
  Region visibleRegionScreen (this=0x14ca430, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
+ Layer 0x14d1320 (StatusBar)
      z=   141000, pos=(0,767), size=(1280,   1), isOpaque=1, needsDithering=0, invalidate=0, alpha=0xff, flags=0x00000000, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0x14d00a0, identity=2
      format= 4, activeBuffer=[1280x   1:1280,  4], transform-hint=0x00, queued-frames=0
            mBufferCount=2, mSynchronousMode=1, default-size=[1280x1], mPixelFormat=4, mTexName=1505553220
            current: {crop=[0,0,-1,-1], transform=0x00, current=0}
            next   : {crop=[0,0,-1,-1], transform=0x00, FIFO(0)={}}
            >[00] state=QUEUED  , crop=[0,0,-1,-1], transform=0x00, timestamp=356044860845, 0x14d0440 [1280x   1:1280,  4]
             [01] state=FREE    , crop=[0,0,-1,-1], transform=0x00, timestamp=0
  Region transparentRegion (this=0x14d14c0, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region transparentRegionScreen (this=0x14d1354, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region visibleRegionScreen (this=0x14d1330, count=1)
    [  0, 767, 1280, 768]
Purgatory state (0 entries)
SurfaceFlinger global state:
GLES: Imagination Technologies, PowerVR SGX 540, OpenGL ES-CM 1.1
EGL : 1.4 build 1.8@785978
EXTS: GL_OES_byte_coordinates GL_OES_fixed_point GL_OES_single_precision GL_OES_matrix_get GL_OES_read_format GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_point_sprite GL_OES_point_size_array GL_OES_matrix_palette GL_OES_draw_texture GL_OES_query_matrix GL_OES_texture_env_crossbar GL_OES_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_OES_texture_cube_map GL_OES_blend_subtract GL_OES_blend_func_separate GL_OES_blend_equation_separate GL_OES_stencil_wrap GL_OES_extended_matrix_palette GL_OES_framebuffer_object GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_stencil8 GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_OES_required_internalformat GL_IMG_read_format GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc GL_IMG_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_OES_egl_sync GL_IMG_vertex_array_object
  Region WormholeRegion (this=0x14b4b04, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  orientation=0, canDraw=1
  last eglSwapBuffers() time: 18798.828000 us
  last transaction time     : 30.517000 us
  refresh-rate              : 52.582001 fps
  x-dpi                     : 160.000000
  y-dpi                     : 160.000000
  eglSwapBuffers time: 3601.074000 us
  h/w composer present and enabled
Hardware Composer state:
  numHwLayers=3, flags=00000000
   type   |  handle  |   hints  |   flags  | tr | blend |  format  |       source crop         |           frame           name 
----------+----------+----------+----------+----+-------+----------+---------------------------+--------------------------------
  OVERLAY | 014d7920 | 00000000 | 00000000 | 00 | 00100 | 00000100 | [    0,    0,  720,  240] | [    0,    0, 1280,  767] SurfaceView
  OVERLAY | 014d9238 | 00000000 | 00000000 | 00 | 00105 | 00000005 | [    0,    0, 1280,  767] | [    0,    0, 1280,  767] SurfaceView
  OVERLAY | 014d0440 | 00000000 | 00000000 | 00 | 00100 | 00000004 | [    0,    0, 1280,    1] | [    0,  767, 1280,  768] StatusBar
omap4_hwc 3:
  idle timeout: 250ms
  layer 0:
     enabled: true
     buff: 0x14d7920 720x480 stride: 736
     src: (0,0) 720x240
     dst: (0,0) 1280x767
     ix: 1
     zorder: 0

  layer 1:
     enabled: true
     buff: 0x14d9238 1280x767 stride: 5120
     src: (0,0) 1280x767
     dst: (0,0) 1280x767
     ix: 0
     zorder: 1

  layer 2:
     enabled: true
     buff: 0x14d0440 1280x1 stride: 2560
     src: (0,0) 1280x1
     dst: (0,767) 1280x1
     ix: 2
     zorder: 2

Allocated buffers:
 0x14cbe48: unknown     |  720 (4096) x  480 |      100 | 0x00002b00
 0x14d0440:    2.50 KiB | 1280 (1280) x    1 |        4 | 0x00000933
 0x14d1928: 6400.00 KiB | 1280 (1280) x 1280 |        5 | 0x00000b00
 0x14d3390: unknown     |  720 (4096) x  480 |      100 | 0x00002b00
 0x14d35d0: unknown     |  720 (4096) x  480 |      100 | 0x00002b00
 0x14d3628: 3835.00 KiB | 1280 (1280) x  767 |        5 | 0x00000b00
 0x14d3900: unknown     |  720 (4096) x  480 |      100 | 0x00002b00
 0x14d7740: unknown     |  720 (4096) x  480 |      100 | 0x00002b00
 0x14d7920: unknown     |  720 (4096) x  480 |      100 | 0x00002b00
 0x14d8520: 3835.00 KiB | 1280 (1280) x  767 |        5 | 0x00000b00
 0x14d9238: 3835.00 KiB | 1280 (1280) x  767 |        5 | 0x00000b00
 0x14d9270: unknown     |  720 (4096) x  480 |      100 | 0x00002b00
 0x14d9300: unknown     |  720 (4096) x  480 |      100 | 0x00002b00
 0x14d93a8: 3835.00 KiB | 1280 (1280) x  767 |        5 | 0x00000b00
Total allocated (estimate): 21742.50 KB
IMG Graphics HAL state:
  Dumping all active sync objects..
    ID=93, 0xP...FHWR=0x00002b00, WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x11/0x10, WOC DevVA=0x0d800fa4, ROC DevVA=0x0d800fac, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800fb4
    ID=91, 0xP...FHWR=0x00002b00, WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x12/0x12, WOC DevVA=0x0d800a84, ROC DevVA=0x0d800a8c, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800a94
    ID=89, 0xP...FHWR=0x00002b00, WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x10/0x10, WOC DevVA=0x0d800f24, ROC DevVA=0x0d800f2c, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800f34
    ID=87, 0xP...FHWR=0x00002b00, WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x10/0x10, WOC DevVA=0x0d800ee4, ROC DevVA=0x0d800eec, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800ef4
    ID=85, 0xP...FHWR=0x00002b00, WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x13/0x13, WOC DevVA=0x0d800ea4, ROC DevVA=0x0d800eac, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800eb4
    ID=83, 0xP...FHWR=0x00002b00, WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x14/0x12, WOC DevVA=0x0d800c64, ROC DevVA=0x0d800c6c, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800c74
    ID=81, 0xP...FHWR=0x00002b00, WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x11/0x11, WOC DevVA=0x0d800c24, ROC DevVA=0x0d800c2c, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800c34
    ID=79, 0xP...FHWR=0x00002b00, WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x15/0x15, WOC DevVA=0x0d800d44, ROC DevVA=0x0d800d4c, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800d54
    ID=30, 0xP...FHWR=0x00000b00, WOP/WOC=0xf26/0xf25, ROP/ROC=0x5c/0x5c, ROP2/ROC2=0xed8/0xed6, WOC DevVA=0x0d8009e4, ROC DevVA=0x0d8009ec, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d8009f4
    ID=29, 0xP...FHWR=0x00000b00, WOP/WOC=0x8/0x8, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0x0d8009c4, ROC DevVA=0x0d8009cc, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d8009d4
    ID=28, 0xP...FHWR=0x00000b00, WOP/WOC=0xf27/0xf25, ROP/ROC=0x6b/0x6b, ROP2/ROC2=0xed5/0xed4, WOC DevVA=0x0d8009a4, ROC DevVA=0x0d8009ac, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d8009b4
    ID=27, 0xP...FHWR=0x00000b00, WOP/WOC=0x8/0x8, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0x0d800e24, ROC DevVA=0x0d800e2c, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800e34
    ID=7, 0xP...FHWR=0x00000933, WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x1/0x1, ROP2/ROC2=0x21e8/0x21e5, WOC DevVA=0x0d8006a4, ROC DevVA=0x0d8006ac, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d8006b4
    ID=5, 0xP...FHWR=0x00000b00, WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0x0d800824, ROC DevVA=0x0d80082c, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800834
    ID=2, 0xP...FHWR=0x00001000, WOP/WOC=0xb8/0xb8, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0xb8/0xb8, WOC DevVA=0x0d800044, ROC DevVA=0x0d80004c, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800054
    ID=1, 0xP...FHWR=0x00001000, WOP/WOC=0xb8/0xb8, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0xb8/0xb8, WOC DevVA=0x0d800024, ROC DevVA=0x0d80002c, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800034
```

But, in our system, the app can be interrupted by another Activity, onPause is trigerred then onResume.

```
Visible layers (count = 6)
+ Layer 0x14cf518 (com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper)
      z=    21000, pos=(0,-256), size=(1280,1280), isOpaque=1, needsDithering=0, invalidate=0, alpha=0xff, flags=0x00000001, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0x14d00a0, identity=3
      format= 2, activeBuffer=[1280x1280:1280,  5], transform-hint=0x00, queued-frames=0
            mBufferCount=2, mSynchronousMode=1, default-size=[1280x1280], mPixelFormat=5, mTexName=-1563003837
            current: {crop=[0,0,0,0], transform=0x00, current=-1}
            next   : {crop=[0,0,-1,-1], transform=0x00, FIFO(0)={}}
             [00] state=FREE    , crop=[0,0,0,0], transform=0x00, timestamp=355968597417
             [01] state=FREE    , crop=[0,0,-1,-1], transform=0x00, timestamp=0
  Region transparentRegion (this=0x14cf6b8, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region transparentRegionScreen (this=0x14cf54c, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region visibleRegionScreen (this=0x14cf528, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
+ LayerDim 0x14ca948 (DimSurface)
      z=    21009, pos=(0,0), size=(1280, 768), isOpaque=0, needsDithering=0, invalidate=0, alpha=0xff, flags=0x00000001, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0x14d0040, identity=6
  Region transparentRegion (this=0x14caae8, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region transparentRegionScreen (this=0x14ca97c, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region visibleRegionScreen (this=0x14ca958, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
+ Layer 0x14d6b68 (SurfaceView)
      z=    21010, pos=(0,0), size=(1280, 767), isOpaque=0, needsDithering=0, invalidate=0, alpha=0xff, flags=0x00000000, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0x14cfdb8, identity=23
      format= 1, activeBuffer=[1280x 767:1280,  5], transform-hint=0x00, queued-frames=1
            mBufferCount=2, mSynchronousMode=1, default-size=[1280x767], mPixelFormat=5, mTexName=1984777172
            current: {crop=[0,0,0,0], transform=0x00, current=0}
            next   : {crop=[0,0,0,0], transform=0x00, FIFO(1)={01 }}
            >[00] state=QUEUED  , crop=[0,0,0,0], transform=0x00, timestamp=1075593353277, 0x14d93a8 [1280x 767:1280,  5]
             [01] state=QUEUED  , crop=[0,0,0,0], transform=0x00, timestamp=1075597686773, 0x14d9238 [1280x 767:1280,  5]
  Region transparentRegion (this=0x14d6d08, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region transparentRegionScreen (this=0x14d6b9c, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region visibleRegionScreen (this=0x14d6b78, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
+ Layer 0x14cbd40 (SurfaceView)
      z=    21015, pos=(0,0), size=(1280, 767), isOpaque=1, needsDithering=0, invalidate=0, alpha=0xff, flags=0x00000000, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0x14cfdb8, identity=29
      format= 1, activeBuffer=[ 720x 480:4096,100], transform-hint=0x00, queued-frames=0
            mBufferCount=8, mSynchronousMode=1, default-size=[1280x767], mPixelFormat=256, mTexName=622950690
            current: {crop=[0,0,720,240], transform=0x00, current=0}
            next   : {crop=[0,0,720,240], transform=0x00, FIFO(0)={}}
            >[00] state=QUEUED  , crop=[0,0,720,240], transform=0x00, timestamp=1075593200689, 0x14d4150 [ 720x 480:4096,100]
             [01] state=DEQUEUED, crop=[0,0,720,240], transform=0x00, timestamp=1075327606206, 0x14d42d8 [ 720x 480:4096,100]
             [02] state=DEQUEUED, crop=[0,0,720,240], transform=0x00, timestamp=1075558044439, 0x14d4460 [ 720x 480:4096,100]
             [03] state=DEQUEUED, crop=[0,0,720,240], transform=0x00, timestamp=1075425262456, 0x14d48a8 [ 720x 480:4096,100]
             [04] state=DEQUEUED, crop=[0,0,720,240], transform=0x00, timestamp=1075458221441, 0x14d4a88 [ 720x 480:4096,100]
             [05] state=DEQUEUED, crop=[0,0,720,240], transform=0x00, timestamp=1075391387945, 0x14d4ce0 [ 720x 480:4096,100]
             [06] state=DEQUEUED, crop=[0,0,720,240], transform=0x00, timestamp=1075490966802, 0x14ca860 [ 720x 480:4096,100]
             [07] state=DEQUEUED, crop=[0,0,720,240], transform=0x00, timestamp=1075524536139, 0x14d9c08 [ 720x 480:4096,100]
  Region transparentRegion (this=0x14cbee0, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region transparentRegionScreen (this=0x14cbd74, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region visibleRegionScreen (this=0x14cbd50, count=1)
    [  0,   0, 1280, 767]
+ Layer 0x14ca420 (com.******.ux.qml/com.*****.ux.qml.*****Activity)
      z=    21020, pos=(0,0), size=(1280, 767), isOpaque=0, needsDithering=0, invalidate=0, alpha=0xff, flags=0x00000000, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0x14cfdb8, identity=22
      format= 1, activeBuffer=[1280x 767:1280,  5], transform-hint=0x00, queued-frames=0
            mBufferCount=2, mSynchronousMode=1, default-size=[1280x767], mPixelFormat=5, mTexName=229433297
            current: {crop=[0,0,0,0], transform=0x00, current=1}
            next   : {crop=[0,0,0,0], transform=0x00, FIFO(0)={}}
             [00] state=DEQUEUED, crop=[0,0,0,0], transform=0x00, timestamp=709190032964, 0x14d8520 [1280x 767:1280,  5]
            >[01] state=QUEUED  , crop=[0,0,0,0], transform=0x00, timestamp=1061756073004, 0x14d3628 [1280x 767:1280,  5]
  Region transparentRegion (this=0x14ca5c0, count=1)
    [  0,   0, 1280, 767]
  Region transparentRegionScreen (this=0x14ca454, count=1)
    [  0,   0, 1280, 767]
  Region visibleRegionScreen (this=0x14ca430, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
+ Layer 0x14d1320 (StatusBar)
      z=   141000, pos=(0,767), size=(1280,   1), isOpaque=1, needsDithering=0, invalidate=0, alpha=0xff, flags=0x00000000, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0x14d00a0, identity=2
      format= 4, activeBuffer=[1280x   1:1280,  4], transform-hint=0x00, queued-frames=0
            mBufferCount=2, mSynchronousMode=1, default-size=[1280x1], mPixelFormat=4, mTexName=1505553220
            current: {crop=[0,0,-1,-1], transform=0x00, current=0}
            next   : {crop=[0,0,-1,-1], transform=0x00, FIFO(0)={}}
            >[00] state=QUEUED  , crop=[0,0,-1,-1], transform=0x00, timestamp=356044860845, 0x14d0440 [1280x   1:1280,  4]
             [01] state=FREE    , crop=[0,0,-1,-1], transform=0x00, timestamp=0
  Region transparentRegion (this=0x14d14c0, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region transparentRegionScreen (this=0x14d1354, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region visibleRegionScreen (this=0x14d1330, count=1)
    [  0, 767, 1280, 768]
Purgatory state (0 entries)
SurfaceFlinger global state:
GLES: Imagination Technologies, PowerVR SGX 540, OpenGL ES-CM 1.1
EGL : 1.4 build 1.8@785978
EXTS: GL_OES_byte_coordinates GL_OES_fixed_point GL_OES_single_precision GL_OES_matrix_get GL_OES_read_format GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture GL_OES_point_sprite GL_OES_point_size_array GL_OES_matrix_palette GL_OES_draw_texture GL_OES_query_matrix GL_OES_texture_env_crossbar GL_OES_texture_mirrored_repeat GL_OES_texture_cube_map GL_OES_blend_subtract GL_OES_blend_func_separate GL_OES_blend_equation_separate GL_OES_stencil_wrap GL_OES_extended_matrix_palette GL_OES_framebuffer_object GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_stencil8 GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_mapbuffer GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays GL_OES_required_internalformat GL_IMG_read_format GL_IMG_texture_compression_pvrtc GL_IMG_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_OES_egl_sync GL_IMG_vertex_array_object
  Region WormholeRegion (this=0x14b4b04, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  orientation=0, canDraw=1
  last eglSwapBuffers() time: 13214.111000 us
  last transaction time     : 30.518000 us
  refresh-rate              : 52.582001 fps
  x-dpi                     : 160.000000
  y-dpi                     : 160.000000
  eglSwapBuffers time: 5187.988000 us
  h/w composer present and enabled
Hardware Composer state:
  numHwLayers=2, flags=00000000
   type   |  handle  |   hints  |   flags  | tr | blend |  format  |       source crop         |           frame           name 
----------+----------+----------+----------+----+-------+----------+---------------------------+--------------------------------
  OVERLAY | 014d4150 | 00000000 | 00000000 | 00 | 00100 | 00000100 | [    0,    0,  720,  240] | [    0,    0, 1280,  767] SurfaceView
  OVERLAY | 014d0440 | 00000000 | 00000000 | 00 | 00100 | 00000004 | [    0,    0, 1280,    1] | [    0,  767, 1280,  768] StatusBar
omap4_hwc 2:
  idle timeout: 250ms
  layer 0:
     enabled: true
     buff: 0x14d4150 720x480 stride: 736
     src: (0,0) 720x240
     dst: (0,0) 1280x767
     ix: 1
     zorder: 0

  layer 1:
     enabled: true
     buff: 0x14d0440 1280x1 stride: 2560
     src: (0,0) 1280x1
     dst: (0,767) 1280x1
     ix: 0
     zorder: 1

Allocated buffers:
 0x14ca860: unknown     |  720 (4096) x  480 |      100 | 0x00002b00
 0x14d0440:    2.50 KiB | 1280 (1280) x    1 |        4 | 0x00000933
 0x14d1928: 6400.00 KiB | 1280 (1280) x 1280 |        5 | 0x00000b00
 0x14d3628: 3835.00 KiB | 1280 (1280) x  767 |        5 | 0x00000b00
 0x14d4150: unknown     |  720 (4096) x  480 |      100 | 0x00002b00
 0x14d42d8: unknown     |  720 (4096) x  480 |      100 | 0x00002b00
 0x14d4460: unknown     |  720 (4096) x  480 |      100 | 0x00002b00
 0x14d48a8: unknown     |  720 (4096) x  480 |      100 | 0x00002b00
 0x14d4a88: unknown     |  720 (4096) x  480 |      100 | 0x00002b00
 0x14d4ce0: unknown     |  720 (4096) x  480 |      100 | 0x00002b00
 0x14d8520: 3835.00 KiB | 1280 (1280) x  767 |        5 | 0x00000b00
 0x14d9238: 3835.00 KiB | 1280 (1280) x  767 |        5 | 0x00000b00
 0x14d93a8: 3835.00 KiB | 1280 (1280) x  767 |        5 | 0x00000b00
 0x14d9c08: unknown     |  720 (4096) x  480 |      100 | 0x00002b00
Total allocated (estimate): 21742.50 KB
IMG Graphics HAL state:
  Dumping all active sync objects..
    ID=125, 0xP...FHWR=0x00002b00, WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x8/0x8, ROP2/ROC2=0x278/0x278, WOC DevVA=0x0d800a64, ROC DevVA=0x0d800a6c, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800a74
    ID=123, 0xP...FHWR=0x00002b00, WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x5/0x5, ROP2/ROC2=0x279/0x279, WOC DevVA=0x0d800f44, ROC DevVA=0x0d800f4c, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800f54
    ID=121, 0xP...FHWR=0x00002b00, WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x11/0x11, ROP2/ROC2=0x36cc/0x36cc, WOC DevVA=0x0d800f04, ROC DevVA=0x0d800f0c, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800f14
    ID=119, 0xP...FHWR=0x00002b00, WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x9/0x9, ROP2/ROC2=0x26d/0x26d, WOC DevVA=0x0d800ec4, ROC DevVA=0x0d800ecc, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800ed4
    ID=117, 0xP...FHWR=0x00002b00, WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0xb/0xb, ROP2/ROC2=0x272/0x272, WOC DevVA=0x0d800c84, ROC DevVA=0x0d800c8c, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800c94
    ID=115, 0xP...FHWR=0x00002b00, WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x8/0x8, ROP2/ROC2=0x26b/0x26a, WOC DevVA=0x0d800c44, ROC DevVA=0x0d800c4c, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800c54
    ID=113, 0xP...FHWR=0x00002b00, WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x8/0x8, ROP2/ROC2=0x26e/0x26e, WOC DevVA=0x0d800c04, ROC DevVA=0x0d800c0c, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800c14
    ID=111, 0xP...FHWR=0x00002b00, WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x8/0x8, ROP2/ROC2=0x272/0x271, WOC DevVA=0x0d800fc4, ROC DevVA=0x0d800fcc, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800fd4
    ID=30, 0xP...FHWR=0x00000b00, WOP/WOC=0x4485/0x4484, ROP/ROC=0xa1/0xa1, ROP2/ROC2=0x4047/0x4047, WOC DevVA=0x0d8009e4, ROC DevVA=0x0d8009ec, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d8009f4
    ID=29, 0xP...FHWR=0x00000b00, WOP/WOC=0xb/0xb, ROP/ROC=0xb/0xb, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0x0d8009c4, ROC DevVA=0x0d8009cc, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d8009d4
    ID=28, 0xP...FHWR=0x00000b00, WOP/WOC=0x4485/0x4484, ROP/ROC=0xac/0xac, ROP2/ROC2=0x4047/0x4047, WOC DevVA=0x0d8009a4, ROC DevVA=0x0d8009ac, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d8009b4
    ID=27, 0xP...FHWR=0x00000b00, WOP/WOC=0xb/0xb, ROP/ROC=0x3f/0x3f, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0x0d800e24, ROC DevVA=0x0d800e2c, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800e34
    ID=7, 0xP...FHWR=0x00000933, WOP/WOC=0x0/0x0, ROP/ROC=0x4a/0x4a, ROP2/ROC2=0x86a7/0x86a5, WOC DevVA=0x0d8006a4, ROC DevVA=0x0d8006ac, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d8006b4
    ID=5, 0xP...FHWR=0x00000b00, WOP/WOC=0x1/0x1, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x0/0x0, WOC DevVA=0x0d800824, ROC DevVA=0x0d80082c, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800834
    ID=2, 0xP...FHWR=0x00001000, WOP/WOC=0x112/0x112, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x112/0x112, WOC DevVA=0x0d800044, ROC DevVA=0x0d80004c, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800054
    ID=1, 0xP...FHWR=0x00001000, WOP/WOC=0x111/0x111, ROP/ROC=0x0/0x0, ROP2/ROC2=0x111/0x111, WOC DevVA=0x0d800024, ROC DevVA=0x0d80002c, ROC2 DevVA=0x0d800034
```

After those calls, something happens with the surface order. The video is displayed **on top** of the QT Surface. The video surfaceView(Layer 0x14d4b10) changed and becomes 0x14cbd40 (so it has been recreated), and its z-order goes from 21010 to 21015. The QTSurface did not changed (0x14d6b68) but the z-order changed (21010 instead of 21015).

I tried to change the z-order at Android level (setZorderOnTop, setZorderMedialOverlay...) but it doesn't have any impact. What looks weird to me is that, when the play is done and the player restarted (video is looping), the surface is recreated, and this time, it is put behind the QTSurfaceView! On the same idea, removing then adding the VOD surfaceView to the tree put it behind the QT (but it causes lot of instability on the player side)

So I'm a bit lost on how Android managed those SurfaceView, if z-order was depending on when the SurfaceView is created, we should have a consistent behavior between onResume and remove/add the SurfaceView. Is there a way to force the z-order? Since we are on an embedded custom platform, we can access to any hidden or native API to get it, we are not limited like a "normal" Android app.

I'm also wondering if the different z-order level on Android (Overlay, media...) side are hardware/implementation-dependent. Is it possible that we can't manage it because our hardware, or maybe OpenGL ES-CM 1.1 doesn't  manage those layers? How to know if it is the case or not?

Any help would be very much appreciated!

**EDIT** : After more investigations (using reflection API to check if values were set correctly), there is no issue on Android Java side. The QTSurface is well set as a media overlay when the video surfaceview is set as a media, but it doesn't prevent the issue. I'm thinking it is something around Android native / OpenGL / Driver.
As a workaround, I found that removing the video surfaceview when the video is fully stopped (player not touching the surface) then adding it back on the onResume seems to re-order the two SurfaceView correctly. I still have to check if this fix is stable enough with the native player but it could do the trick...

Comment: did you manage to fix this?